# Prove that $\int_X |f| d\mu = \int_{0}^{\infty} \lambda(\alpha)d\alpha$

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Here, I have old question on distribution function.

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space and let $\lambda(\alpha) = \mu(\left\{x\in X : |f(x)|>\alpha   \right\})$.

Firstly, prove that, for $f\in L^1(X)$,

$\int_X |f| d\mu = \int_X \left(\int_{0}^{|f|} d\alpha \right) d\mu$.

After that, by using the above, prove that

$\int_X |f| d\mu = \int_{0}^{\infty} \lambda(\alpha)d\alpha$.

Comment: So, you are asking why $$|f| = \int_{0}^{|f|} d\alpha\ ?$$

Comment: @Did Yes indeed...  Is there any argument to show that? For me that is obvious... But problem asked me to verify.

Comment: "Is there any argument to show that?" There is: compute the RHS.

Comment: Hmm..... Okay..... Thanks

Comment: You don't do anything with $\lambda(\alpha) $. Any reason why you defined it?

Comment: @Shashi I was proving different thing.. I edited my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda\left(\alpha\right)d\alpha=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{X}1_{\left(\alpha,\infty\right)}\left(\left|f\right|\right)d\mu d\alpha$

Now switch the order of integration.

Comment: By switching the order of integration, can I get $\int_X (\int_{0}^{|f|}d\alpha)  d\mu$? Could you give me more details?

Comment: $\int_0^{|f|}d\alpha=|f|$

Comment: Sorry, I need some details between $\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_X 1_{(\alpha,\infty)}(|f|)d\mu d\alpha$ and $\int_X(\int_{0}^{|f|}d\alpha  )d\mu$.

Comment: $\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{X}1_{(\alpha,\infty)}\left(|f|\right)d\mu d\alpha=\int_{X}\int_{0}^{\infty}1_{(\alpha,\infty)}(|f|)d\alpha d\mu=\int_{X}\int_{0}^{|f|}d\alpha d\mu=\int_{X}|f|d\mu$

Comment: Thank you so much!